# Question about regular elements in a Lie subalgebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group and $T$ is a maximal torus of $G$. Let $K$ be a non trivial connected Lie subgroup of $G$.

We say that $r \in \mathfrak{g}$ is a regular element of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ if the stabilizer subgroup $G_r$ of the adjoint action of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ is a maximal torus of $G$.

We fix a maximal torus $T_K$ of $K$.

2. Does there exist a regular element $r$ of both the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{k}$ such that the stabilizer $G_r$ is equal to $T$ and the stabilizer subgroup $K_r$ is equal to $T_K$ ?

Comment: In 1, $K$ should be assumed nontrivial to make the question non-tautological. And you should clarify what is meant by "intersects it". Has intersection not reduced to $\{1\}$? has infinite intersection? Anyway, what do you think of the case when $T,K$ are two distinct maximal tori in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$?

Comment: @YCor, thanks for your comment . I'll edit my question.

Comment: I think I have answered (negatively) your question 1 for $G=\mathrm{SO}(3)$. Have you thought of this special case for question 2?

Comment: No, I didn't think of any examples, but I'd like to see yours. My thoughts of the second question are to use the fact that the set of regular elements in any Lie algebra is an open dense set and to use the fact that the Lie groups $G$ and $K$ are compact and connected, but I'm not sure if this is sufficient.

Comment: I think that thinking of accessible examples is the first thing to do before asking a question.

Comment: Now that you have deleted Question 1, what is $T$?  Just any torus containing $T_K$?  If so, then you can delete this extra condition; if $r$ is regular in both $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak k$, then its connected centraliser $T$ in $G$ will necessarily contain its connected centraliser $T_K$ in $K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have a non-trivial, closed, connected Lie subgroup $K$ of a compact, connected Lie group $G$ such that no element of $\mathfrak k$ is regular in $\mathfrak g$.  For example, consider $K = \operatorname{SU}_2$ embedded in $G = \operatorname{SU}_4$ as $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a &&& b \\ & a & b \\ & c & d \\ c &&& d \end{pmatrix}$.

On second thought, even this is overkill; you could just take $K$ to be the (non-trivial) central torus in $G = \operatorname U_2$.  But maybe you wanted a non-central as well as non-trivial example.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer @LSpice !